# What's the problem in my for loop code to seperate and make a new DataFrame from my origin Data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I'm beginner at Python and Pandas.

I have origin Data what i defined F1 and shape (194000,4).

I wanna split it into 97 groups of 2,000 each (ex. Index num 0~1999 is F1_0, 2000~3999 is F1_1)

And i wrote code like below.

```
n=0
for i in (0, 97):
  num=2000*(i+1)
  globals()['F1_{0}'.format(i)] = F1.loc[n:num]
  n = A
```

When i call F1_0, there is no problem.

But From F1_1 to F1_96, there is "no define error".

I don't know what's the reason in my code :(

And i'd appreciate if you could let me know if there is better way.

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0):

Using `range` instead of only passing a tuple in the loop. In your code, for loop will iterates the value `0` and `97` only, not the range `(0, ..., 96)`.

```
n=0
for i in range(97):
    num=2000*(i+1)
    globals()['F1_{0}'.format(i)] = F1.loc[n:num]
```